# HTML form data not inserting correctly into MySQL using xampp

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know this question has been asked before, and I looked at many different solutions. But please still help. I will cut to the chase, I am trying to insert data taken from a survey into my SQL database.
EDIT 1: I figured out how to prevent the unidentified array. I had just specified where data should go to. See the php below.
EDIT 2: Thank you all so much for the feedback. I only have one problem left.

Say if a user selects multiple checkboxes. How can I get the values from check buttons to appear within the same column?

Ex: yes

20-40

Pfizer

Pain, Swelling

Chills, Fever, Nausea

I'm not sure where the problem is as I am just beginning this project after following some tutorials and going through w3schools.
Here's the HTML form

```
<body>
<h1>Covid Vaccine Experience Survey</h1>

<!-- Create Form  "action" will send the submit button to the result page-->
<form id="form" action="site.php" method="post"> 
    
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>
            1. *This Survey is Only for Vaccinated Particapants*
            Are you Vaccinated?
        </label>

        <!-- Input Type Radio Button -->
        <label for="answer-1">
            <input type="radio"
                   id="answer-1"
                   name="answer">Yes</input>
        </label>
        <label for="answer-2">
            <input type="radio"
                   id="answer-2"
                   name="answer">No</input>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-control">
        <label>
            2. What is you're Age Group?
        </label>

        <!--Input Type Radio Button -->
        <label for="agegroup-1">
            <input type="radio"
                   id="agegroup-1"
                   name="agegroup" required>5-12</input>
        </label>
        <label for="agegroup-2">
            <input type="radio"
                   id="agegroup-2"
                   name="agegroup">12-19</input>
        </label>
        <label for="agegroup-3">
            <input type="radio"
                   id="agegroup-3"
                   name="agegroup">20-40</input>
        </label>
        <label for="agegroup-4">
            <input type="radio"
                   id="agegroup-4"
                   name="agegroup">50-69</input>
        </label>
        <label for="agegroup-5">
            <input type="radio"
                   id="agegroup-5"
                   name="agegroup">70+</input>
        </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="Vaccine">
            3. Select Vaccine type:
            <small>(Click the Dropdown icon for more vaccines)</small>
        </label>

        <!--Input Type Dropdown -->
        <select name = "vaccines" id="vaccines">
            <option value="pfizer">Pfizer</option>
            <option value="maderna">Maderna</option>
            <option value="johnsone">Johnsone</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-control">
        <label>
        4. Physical Side Effects Reported
        <small>(Check all that apply)</small>
        </label>
        <!-- Input Type Checkbox -->
        <label for="inp-1">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inp" value="Pain" onclick="return PhysicalSideEffects();">Pain</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-2">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inp"value="Swelling" onclick="return PhysicalSideEffects();">Swelling</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-3">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inp"value="Redness" onclick="return PhysicalSideEffects();">Redness</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-4">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inp"value="Rash" onclick="return PhysicalSideEffects();">Rash</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-5">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inp"value="None" onclick="return PhysicalSideEffects();">None</input>
                </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label>
            5. Illness Side Effects Reported
            <small>(Check all that apply)</small>
        </label>
        <!--Input Type Checkbox -->
        <label for="inp-1">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inps" value="Headache" onclick="return IllnessSideEffects();">Headache</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-2">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inps"value="Chills" onclick="return IllnessSideEffects();">Chills</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-3">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inps"value="Dirrahea" onclick="return IllnessSideEffects();">Dirrahea</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-4">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inps"value="Tiredness" onclick="return IllnessSideEffects();">Tiredness</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-5">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inps"value="Fever" onclick="return IllnessSideEffects();">Fever</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-6">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inps"value="Dizziness" onclick="return IllnessSideEffects();">Dizziness</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-7">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inps"value="Nausea" onclick="return IllnessSideEffects();">Nausea</input>
                </label>
        <label for="inp-8">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="inps"value="None" onclick="return IllnessSideEffects();">None</input>
                </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return confirm('6. Are you sure what you have is true to your knowledge?')">
    <!-- This function is *figure this out*(to check whether or  not the user selected an illness) & *works* make sure that they do not select another ilness if they selected "None"-->
    <form>
        <script type="text/javascript">  
        
            function PhysicalSideEffects()  
            {  
                var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("inp");  // Gets the the different checkboxes 
                var numberOfCheckedItems = 0;  //Holder for number of checked items
                for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)  //Loops through counting how many are checked
                {  
                    if(checkboxes[i].checked)  
                        numberOfCheckedItems++;  
                }  
                if(checkboxes[4].checked && (checkboxes[0].checked || checkboxes[1].checked || checkboxes[2].checked || checkboxes[3].checked))  
                {  
                    alert("You can't select another Illness if you selected None!");  
                    return false;  
                }
               
            } 
            
            function IllnessSideEffects()
            {
                var checkboxes= document.getElementsByName("inps");
                var num = 0;
                for(var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++)
                {

                    if(checkboxes[j].checked)
                        num++;
                }
                if(checkboxes[7].checked && (checkboxes[0].checked || checkboxes[1].checked || checkboxes[2].checked || checkboxes[3].checked
                || checkboxes[4].checked || checkboxes[5].checked || checkboxes[6].checked))
                {
                    alert("You can't select another Illness if you selected None!");  
                    return false;
                }
            }
        
            </script>
```

Here is the newer PHP code

```
<?php

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","csurv");
    //connection established

    if($conn === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " 
            . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $agegroup = $_POST['agegroup'];
    $vaccines = $_POST['vaccines'];
    $inp = $_POST['inp'];
    $inps = $_POST['inps'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO submisiion (qualified, agegroup, vaccinetype, physsymptoms, illsymptoms)
            VALUES('$answer','$agegroup','$vaccines','$inp','$inps')";
    
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        echo "<h3>data stored in a database successfully." 
            . " Please browse your localhost php my admin" 
            . " to view the updated data</h3>"; 

        echo nl2br("\n$answer\n $agegroup\n "
            . "$vaccines\n $inp\n $inps");
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Hush! Sorry $sql. " 
            . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Please help. Looks like I'm too dumb for this.

Comment: not sql-injection proof

Comment: Funny enough, I just learned about sql-injection and hope to come back to this project at a later date to prevent the data from being altered. But for now, this is all I can do.

Comment: check this article https://www.guru99.com/mysql-php-and-other-database-access-methods.html

Comment: I’m not seeing a form field with a name of `vaccinetype`, it looks like it should be `vaccines`. Probably others, too

Comment: @ChrisHaas You're right about that.

Comment: For the radio buttons, Have you specified the value for each ? For example, Should <input type="radio" id="agegroup-5" name="agegroup">
be <input type="radio" id="agegroup-5" name="agegroup" value="agegroup-5"> ?

Comment: @KenLee Thank you! Specifying the value for each radio button works!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the error message, then test the point.
(*ﾟ∀ﾟ*)
In your case, you need to check the line 20 in "C:\xampp\htdocs\site.php" if it's really get the post data "qualified".
You can dump variable $_POST to check if the key is typed correct.

If no problem, it still show this error, go to html page, press key "F12", click "network", when you submit the form, you should see the network-package in there, click it and check if datas in that is in expected.

( ･ὢ･)
If you don't see the the correct datas in that, then the problem probably is in html page.

Comment: Hey! I did what you said and dug a little deeper. 
Edited the php file so that I'm supposed to get the global variables from the html file and then insert them into the database. It works better now.

Comment: Congraculation :)

Comment: You debugged it yourself :)

Comment: Guess I'm not so dumb after all.